# How to keep same random string for both file's name and stored filed?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set unique file name In both `move_uploaded_file` and `update_field("filedName", $fileNameEncoded, $postID);`

But the problem Is they both get two different ones!

```
$fileNameEncoded = hash("sha1", basename($fileName)."-".bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32))).".".$fileExtension;
$fileNameEncoded = str_replace(".", "",uniqid($fileNameEncoded, true));
$fileNameEncoded = $filePath.$fileNameEncoded.".".$file_extension; 

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileNameEncoded);
update_field("filedName", $fileNameEncoded, $postID);
}
```

I've tried too many different ways and codes but It keeps doing the same.

Comment: code seems to be fine. Can you share update_field() function details?

Comment: This is WordPress plus ACF, right? Is `filedName` correct or a typo?

Comment: can you dump $fileNameEncoded right before move_uploaded_file() and after ?
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
var_dump($fileNameEncoded);
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileNameEncoded);
var_dump($fileNameEncoded); exit;
update_field("filedName", $fileNameEncoded, $postID);
}

Does them the same ?

Comment: @AndriiSukhoi Thanks heaps for your reply, Yes I can see the file's name and the input value now are the same, but I honestly don't understand what var_dump does? It's has removed the whole front-end page's content and printed `string(95) "cdn/uploads/92ce94274cffbe6227596463909.mp3"` instead! So I don't know how to use Is properly, I did exactly like how you mentioned In the code above!

Comment: @AndriiSukhoi How can I hide the output of var_dump Please

Comment: @Alli2021 var_dump just print some value to the screen. Okay, so if the value of $fileNameEncoded is the same, why do you think that  update_field get other different value of $fileNameEncoded?